# Circuit for connecting externally power instrument to MCU

Tags: microcontroller, operational-amplifier, adc, differential, diode-clamp

I have externally powered instruments that I need connected to the ADC inputs of an MCU. They output 0-5V analog, and the MCU accepts 0-3.33V. There is no guarantee of the voltage difference in grounding, although they should be connected to the same building ground (who knows where).

I'm stumped on the most efficient circuit for this:

- Differential voltage measurement (to eliminate many sources of noise)
- Voltage divider (5.5 -> 3.3)
- Voltage clamp (to prevent overload to the MCU)
- Are not connected to the same ground locally

With some tries, this is the best that I've come up with. However, I'm not sure it's even theoretically a good design to accomplish this.

**Updated circuit using AD623**
[image: new circuit]

Comment: how far is the source away from the MCU?

Comment: Worst case, probably 3 meters of cable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This schematic is rather useless :

- It has low input impedance: if the source has, say, 50-100R output impedance, which is common, then your input voltage divider will be off by quite a wide margin.
- It has unbalanced input impedances, and thus nearly non-existent CMRR

If you don't need balanced, forget about it, use a voltage divider with much higher resistor values, and a follower. Or no follower, if the bandwidth is now.

If you need a balanced/differential receiver, a much better solution would be a real instrumentation amplifier like  AD8421. Its CMRR is humongous, and as a bonus, it will tolerate input overvoltage up to 40V above the opposite rail, so your inputs will not blow even if your board is unpowered and connected to a powered source.

However, it will not work on your 3V3 supply.

If you have other supplies on your board, then good. If all you have is 3V3 then you could look for a similar chip which will be compatible with your supply.

Comment: I'm sure the schematic is useless - it's been a long time since I've had to work with circuits. There is a step-up voltage regulator on the board that outputs 5V, which seems compatible with the needs of the AD8421 (although I'll look for a through-hole version for testing). Let me draw up a circuit using what I think would work with this one.

Comment: Other chips could fit your needs better... you should shop around. I mentioned this one for inspiration, but I didn't even check if it was rail to rail, which you really need. Also, don't attempt to build differential receivers, as you will need precision matched resistors for CMRR... and it will cost you more than a readymade chip. Basically these chips are laser trimmed precision resistors, with the opamps thrown in for free.

Comment: Two questions came to mind while trying to draw this: 1) should the instrument amplifier come first (connected directly to the inputs), followed by the voltage divider (assuming the amp has a Vss of 5V)? and 2) although I want the differential input for CMRR, the inputs themselves should really only be unipolar, so I'm confused how to set the reference for the amp - just ground itself?

Comment: If your diffamp is rail to rail, supplied with 5V, and has a gain of 1, then you can put the divider after it since your input is 0-5V. Putting the divider first will need a divider with matched impedances and degrade CMRR... Not that easy! Are you sure you need balanced?

Comment: OW CRAP... I just saw "There is no guarantee of the voltage difference in grounding, although they should be connected to the same building ground". This makes it much more complicated, because now you need a differential amplifier whose input common mode can go below GND and above its supply. Or you need to change the requirements.

Comment: I thought this was the point of using a differential input. I was concerned with just tying the ground input from the instrument with the MCU, because 1) there could be noise picked up in the environment that would need more complicated means to eliminate 2) I wanted to prevent the possibility of ground loops.

Comment: The chip I quoted will *survive* common mode overvoltages but its output will be undefined...  I just googled "very wide common mode range differential amplifier", check out AD8479, INA149, LT6375 etc

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54330/discussion-between-adam-jones-and-peufeu).

Answer (score 0):

The updated circuit looks functional additional this [article](http://www.mosaic-industries.com/embedded-systems/microcontroller-projects/measurement-techniques/instrumentation-amplifier-ground-loop-isolator) explain the Mitigating ground loop offsets and also explain and suggest a differential configuration, which may be helpful to you

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> There is no guarantee of the voltage difference in grounding

a few options:

1. try to convert the analog signal to digital locally and then transmit that to the mcu.
2. linear opto-couplers exist for cases like this.
3. convert it to an ac signal and transmit that via transformers -> like xdsl.